# Best practices for replacing regex pattern with other regex pattern in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to come up with some code that will replace a custom shortcode tag with a vue component's html tag that includes a different regex code in it. From what I can see, preg_replace seems to only allow regex in the first "pattern" space, but not in the "replacement" space, so I was wondering what the best practices would be for this?

An example of what I'm trying to do:

there could be multiple components on one page

the markdown would look something like:

```
Cooking lessons

[test|1]

[test|2]
```

where `test` is the type of component and `1` or `2` is the ID of said component

The goal is to have the shortcode replaced in this way:

```
Cooking lessons

<Test id="1" />

<Test id="2" />
```

I've got the standard `preg_replace()` going like so:

```
return preg_replace('[\[test.*]', '<Test id="" />', $text);
```

is the only option to do something like a `preg_match` for the IDs and put them into the `preg_replace` that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~\[test\|(\d+)]~', '<Test id="$1" />', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRCBX8/1/). *Details*:

- `\[test\|` - `[test|` substring
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

If you need to match any text up to the first `]` rather than just digits, replace `\d+` with `[^][]*`.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/oB1jp):

```php
$string = "Cooking lessons\n\n[test|1]\n\n[test|2]";
echo preg_replace('~\[test\|(\d+)]~', '<Test id="$1" />', $string);
```

Output:

```php
Cooking lessons

<Test id="1" />

<Test id="2" />
```